# Show that n $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i$ and $\prod_{i=1}^n c_i$ are rational numbers.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, summation, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, products

Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $A ∈ M_{n×n}(\mathbb{Q})$. Let $c_1,...,c_n$ be the list of
(not necessarily distinct) eigenvalues of $A$, considered as a matrix in $M_{n×n}(\mathbb{C})$.
Show that 
$\sum_{i=1}^n c_i$ and $\prod_{i=1}^n c_i$ are rational numbers.

I'm not sure how to proceed, any solutions/hints are greatly appreciated. This result seems really interesting

Comment: The eigenvalues or $A$ are the roots of the [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial), which is $P_A(x)=\det(xI-A)$. This polynomial has rational coefficients, since the elements of $A$ are rational. Now use [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** The sum and product of the eigenvalues are the trace respectively the determinant of the matrix.